# How pointers are passed across void and non void recursive functions in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

I have the following function to reverse a linked list:

```
Node* reverseUtil(Node *head, Node *prev) {
    if (head->next == NULL) {
        head->next = prev;
        return head;
    }
    Node *next = head->next;
    head->next = prev;
    prev = head;
    head = next;
    return reverseUtil(head, prev);
}
```

When I call this with `Node* head = reverseUtil(head, NULL);` it works fine and ultimately returns the head of the reversed linked list. Example for 1->2->3, it returns head with 3->2->1.

However, when I modify it to the following, the resultant head pointer only has the last node of the reversed linked list (originally the starting point of the list. Example: for original list 1->2->3, head at the end only has 1.

```
void reverseUtil(Node *head, Node *prev) {
    if (head->next == NULL) {
        head->next = prev;
        return;
    }
    Node *next = head->next;
    head->next = prev;
    prev = head;
    head = next; //head pointer should update here on forward path. This seems to be happening.
    reverseUtil(head, prev);//after this step returns, head should stick to the last updated point and should return unchanged but this does not happen.
}
```

I think I am missing something basic here. I would expect that the statement `head = next` at each call of the function would update the head pointer. It should ultimately point to the new beginning of the reversed linked list and should remain unchanged as the recursive calls return. However it seems to be continuously getting updated on the return path.

Comment: You need to pass the pointer by reference if you don't want to return it.,

Comment: Sorry but why is that. Shouldnt the pointer get dynamically updated and persist?

Comment: Providing a reference like `Node *&head,`  should solve your problem. You're actually updating a copy that's not seen in the calling code.

Comment: "I would expect that the statement `head = next` at each call of the function would update the head pointer."  It updates the `head` **parameter**, which is probably not the "head pointer" you are thinking of.

Comment: You return a pointer, or use two stars, (or one star and a typedef).  One star on its own will not work.

Comment: @doomguy In any case your function is wrong becaue in general case head can be equal to NULL.

Comment: Sorry about missing that condition here

Comment: I was checking that in the calling function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a pointer to a function like `void foo(type* bar)` the address that the pointer contains is passed by value.  If you need to change that address then you need to pass it by reference like `void foo(type *&bar)`.  I think that you are confused by the fact that this works

```
void foo(int * bar) { *bar = 10; }

int man() 
{
    int x = 5;
    foo(&x);
    // x is now 10 here
}
```

Here we are not changing what the pointer points to but we are changing the value of the pointed to object.  We can see that changing the address of the pointer has no affect when not passed by reference with:

```
void foo(int * bar)
{
    int foobar = 10;
    bar = &foobar;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    foo(&x);
    std::cout << x;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5548b608e16a869)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. I think this makes it clear. I was actually confused about this.